# Topmargin 0 not working? Caching issue?

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

I can't seem to get my `margin-top:0;` property to work in my style sheet. I'm not sure why, but when I clear my browser's cache, the property will work temporarily, and then go right back to leaving a space at the top of my page (take a look: www.sunporchhomes.com). I'm using Wordpress to build. Here's the top half of my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**CSS**

```
body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-image:url("http://www.sunporchhomes.com/sphbg5.png");
}

a:link {color:#ffffff;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#ffffff;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#808080;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#ffffff;}  /* selected link */

a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a:active {text-decoration:none;}

#logo {
    margin: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 26;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

#header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 175;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left:70px;
}

#banner {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 419px;
            z-index: -1;
        }

#navigationtable {
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:730px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">

   <img id="banner" src="http://sunporchhomes.com/spmain1.png" alt="Banner Image"/>

       <div id="navigationtable">
<table class="tg" width="400">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-lhfu"><a href="http://sunporchomes.com">HOME</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/warranty.html">WARRANTY</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th class="tg-lhfu"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/features-3.html">FEATURES</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/faq-2.html">ROWHOME FAQ</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th class="tg-lhfu"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/floor-plan-2.html">FLOORPLAN</th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/about.html">ABOUT US</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th class="tg-lhfu"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/neighbourhood.html">NEIGHBOURHOOD</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com/contact.html">CONTACT</a></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
  </tr>

</table>
</div>

 <div id="boxplus">
 <img src="http://sunporchhomes.com/boxplus.png" />
 </div>

 <div id="logo">   
    <img src="http://sunporchhomes.com/splogo13.png" /> 

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your css has `.wrapper`, your html has `id="wrapper"` - should change css to `#wrapper` to properly address that element.

Comment: Where is this top margin being applied?

Comment: Also, you've got your `nav` set to `position:absolute` - so your padding-left and padding-right are not useful for positioning (which seems how you are using them)

Comment: Which browser is causing this problem? Working properly for me in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is not your css, but rather is your WordPress admin bar.

When you are logged into WordPress, it attempts to "forcefully" draw an admin bar across the top 32 pixels of your browser window.

When your css conflicts with how WP tries to do this (which your css I believe *does*, due to your heavy use of `position: absolute`), you can be left with a blank space at the top rather than the admin bar.

You can disable the admin bar by editing your user profile, and unchecking "Show Toolbar when viewing site"

I've tested in Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer - they all render your site properly, without the space you described.